# 自分のブラウザだけにcssが反映されていない(キャッシュ削除もしてみました。)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, heroku, browser

railsのアプリなのですが、herokuでデプロイ後動作をchrome, safari, firefoxで確認したのですが、どれもcssが適用されていません。キャッシュの削除も試したがダメでした。友人のpcでは問題なく表示されてるのに何故か私のだけがダメな状況です。要素を検証した結果、`file not found`となり、そもそもcssの読み込みがエラーになっています。どうすれば解決できるか、あらかたググりましたが未だに未解決です。ご教授お願いします。

Comment: 逆に友人のPCにキャッシュが残ってるという可能性はありませんか？ 一度も該当ページを開いたことがない端末から見てもcssが読み込めてるか確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

> 要素を検証した結果、file not foundとなり、
>   そもそもcssの読み込みがエラーになっています。

この検証はどのように行いましたか？ 
chrome で ディベロッパーツールを開いて、ネットワーク の Status が 302 
になっている と言うことですか？

他にも not found になっているファイルが無いか調べてみることで何かわかるかもしれません。

一般的には自分だけ キャッシュ更新されない場合は proxy サーバーで キャッシュされている場合があり、 その場合は URL に ?20160920 など CSS ファイル作成のバージョン情報を付加して、最新版を取りに行くように指示するという方法を使います。